# Probably a bug in Chrome when setting value of input type="text" that uses React

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Some time ago I was hired to make small changes in this website "http://www.clinicasaudevisual.com/contact". I cant access all the code of that website. I can only insert any JS code at the bottom of `<body>` tag. This is important, we dont need to debate that, **I have only access to the bottom of the `<body>` tag**.

So, my problem is this: I need to fill the input EMAIL form field of the link "http://www.clinicasaudevisual.com/contact" with something like "non-mandatory@host.com". We want to make this email field NOT MANDATORY, but the way it is configured today in this website, this field is mandatory.

So I thought: maybe after page load I could just easily do this:

```
document.getElementsByName("Email")[0].value = "non-mandatory@host.com";
```

Yep, it works, till I try to send the form so a message says that the field was not filled correctly. This form uses React and a while ago I discovered that in order to make this change **I should set the value of the input and at the end fire the "TextEvent" event with the last character in it so I could easily pass the validation done in this form**.

Ok, this worked till last week, when Chrome got updated. So now this method of firing TextEvent DOES NOT INSERT THE LAST CHARACTER ANY MORE.

If you want to check this supposed bug by yourself do this: open "http://www.clinicasaudevisual.com/contact" in your Chrome browser with latest version and after page loads execute this code below in your browser console:

```
my_element = document.getElementsByName("Email")[0];

content = "non-mandatory@host.com";
my_element.value = content.substr(0,content.length - 1);

var my_event = document.createEvent("TextEvent");    
my_event.initTextEvent("textInput",true,false,window,content[content.length - 1]);

//For some reason react demands "focus" to be made before making any change.
my_element.focus();

my_element.dispatchEvent(my_event);
```

You will see that the email field will get filled (not the last letter, the bug is already showing itself here). Now, try to send the form clicking the ENVIAR BUTTON. You will see an error message will come up saying that the email is invalid. So clearly the TextEvent is not being fired correctly in the newest version of chrome, so how can I fix this bug or overcome it?

PS: I only need Chrome compatibility, no worry about IE or Firefox or any other browser.